# get a var from inside an .foreach

Tags: node.js, foreach, discord.js

**problem**

the value of affiliateXp dont show outside of the `.foreach`

**code:**

```
//get affiliateXp
let affiliateXp = 0

let invitedUsers = await userSchema.find({
    invitedById: userID
})

invitedUsers.forEach(async user => {

    let userXp = await getXpPerUser(user.discordId)
    affiliateXp = await affiliateXp + 1000 + userXp.totalXp*0.1
    console.log ('inside', affiliateXp)
        
});

console.log ('outside', affiliateXp)
```

**console:**

> outside 0
>
> outside 0
>
> inside 1000.1073925
>
> outside 0
>
> inside 2000.1073925
>
> outside 0
>
> inside 3002.3100682
>
> outside 0
>
> inside 1000

Comment: The use of async/await with forEach is an antipattern, a promise is ignored. Use for..of.

Answer (score 0):

try using a global variable by declaring:
`var affiliateXp = 0` instead of `let affiliateXp = 0`

Comment: same thing, dont work